# how to create files that retain column names with specific values

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file where first column takes certain values (in this case 4)

```
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
city,0 0 2,grind
```

I want to construct 3 files one with 3 column values, one with 2 column values and one with 1 column value. *In addition one of those values has to be "product"

**file3.txt**

```
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
```

**file2.txt**

```
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
```

**file1.txt**

```
product,0 0,no way
product,0 0 1,sugar
```

Can this procedure be automated in awk?
At this point I am manually making the file with column names to retain and using this

```
awk 'NR==FNR{v[$1]; next} $1 in v' values.txt FS=, datafile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=","}
{ 
    if (length(w) < m && !($1 in w)) w[$1]=1
    if ($1 in w) print
}
```

chmod it and invoke it like

```
$ ./script.awk -v m=3 datafile > file3.txt
```

where `m` is the number of unique values

## EDIT

Loop

```
for m in $(seq 100); do ./script.awk -v m=$m datafile > file$m.txt; done
```

Comment: It can be written in a somewhat more idiomatic way, but this is the same logic I came up with.

Comment: Can I mix bash loop with awk?  for m in $(seq 1 100)
do
  doSomething($m)
done

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question a bit based on my needs. Is there a way to also ensure that we always include one particular column value "product" always in the selection?

Comment: Pass another variable to the script, like m, and add the value to the array in the BEGIN block

Comment: I used this bash script #!/bin/bash
for m in $(seq 1 50); do
   ./script.awk -v m=$m new_test.csv > file$mi.txt;
done and got the error "(FILENAME=new_test.csv FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `w' as an array"

Answer (score 0):

This lacks a certain elegance, but it works.

```
awk -F, '{
if(!one) one=$1;
if(!two && $1 != one) two=$1;
if(!three && $1 != one && $1 != two) three=$1;

if (one && $1==one) {print $0 > "file1.txt"; print $0 > "file2.txt"; print $0 > "file3.txt";}
if (two && $1==two) {print $0 > "file2.txt"; print $0 > "file3.txt";}
if (three && $1==three) print $0 > "file3.txt";
}' values.txt
```